# Getting java.io.EOFException: Response contained no data when invoking a Rest API from Weblogic using CXF

Tags: apache, cxf, weblogic11g, cxfrs, cxf-client

When i am invoking a rest API using JAXRS i am receiving an EOFException.

When i run the same as an standalone Java Application. It is working fine and i am getting the response. But the same when i execute in Weblogic 10.3 I am receiving the EOFException.

Below the Code snippet.

```
  JAXRSClientFactoryBean jaxRSClientFactoryBean = new JAXRSClientFactoryBean(); 
          jaxRSClientFactoryBean.setAddress( "https://api.testing.net:443/api/v1/Account?AccountId=9");
          System.out.println(" URL: " +  jaxRSClientFactoryBean.getAddress()); 
          WebClient restClient =  jaxRSClientFactoryBean.createWebClient();
          restClient.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
          restClient.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
          restClient.header("Authorization", "basic xxxxxxx");
          HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new  HTTPClientPolicy();
          httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
          httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(30000);
          httpClientPolicy.setConnection(ConnectionType.CLOSE);
          httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
          http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
          String responseStr =  restClient.get(String.class);
          System.out.println("Response Received"+responseStr);
```

When i Execute the same in Weblogic. I am getting the below Exception.

```
   
        Caused by: java.io.EOFException: EOFException invoking https://api.testing.net:443/api/v1/Account?AccountId=9: Response contained no data
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1336)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1320)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:622)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        ... 147 more
        Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Response contained no data
        at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.isHTTP(MessageHeader.java:227)
        at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.parseHeader(MessageHeader.java:148)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:468)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:377)
        at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:965)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.getResponseCode(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:248)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1515)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1488)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1307)
```

Any pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution?